# Deleting duplicates in list of lists in Python 2.7

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, duplicates

- `Trenutno_stanje` is list
- `povijest` is list of lists
- `epsilon_okolina` is function that gives list for a string (`pocetno`):

  ```
  trenutno_stanje.append(pocetno)
  trenutno_stanje.extend(epsilon_okolina[pocetno])
  povijest.append(trenutno_stanje)
  ```

`povijest` should be essentialy list of lists, but it somehow in code duplicates entities
in a way it can be avoided.

What I would like to know is how to remove duplicate of strings in lists of a list?
I tried:

```
for p in povijest:
    p=list(set(p))
```

But it changed nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> b = [[1,2,3, 3], [3, 2, 4,4]]
>>> b = [ list(set(x)) for x in b ] 
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: This does not answer OP's question. His original list is more like ` b = [['one', 'two'], ['two']]`

Comment: Im talkin about 
>>>b=[['one'],['one'],['two','three']]
>>>...
>>b
[['one'],['two','three'],

Comment: @Larcend No you did not. Consider the 2D list `b = [[1,2,3,3],[3,2,4,4],[1,2,3,3]]` Notice the first and third list are identical. He wants only one of the lists to remain, not duplicates within a particular list.

Comment: Ok it doesnt have duplicates now and thanks for that, but now it doesnt want to be sorted,lol

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop you are just reassigning `p` and not actually changing the `povijest` list.  Also, `set` only works on hashable types, and `list` certainly is not one.  You want to use list comprehension after you cast the lists inside the main list into something that can be hashed (like a `tuple`, which is an immutable list) and then turn that into a set.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> c = [1, 3, 4]
>>> i1 = [a, b, c]
>>> set([tuple(x) for x in i1])
set([(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 3, 4)])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you curious about the order try this ,

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b=[2,3,1,2]
>>> c=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> z=[a,b,c]
>>> dict((x[0], x) for x in z).values()
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 1, 2]]
```